IF $a+b+c=0$ prove that $ \frac{a^5 +b^5 +c^5}{5}=\frac{a^3 + b^3 +c^3}{3}\frac{a^2 + b^2 +c^2}{2}=abc\frac{a^2 +b^2 +c^2}{2} $
First thing that I did is prove that $abc\frac{a^3 + b^3 +c^3}{3} \times \frac{a^2 + b^2 +c^2}{2}=abc\times\frac{a^2 +b^2 +c^2}{2}$
I did this by using identity that I needed to prove before $a^3 +b^3 +c^3 -3abc=(a^2 +b^2 +c^2 -(ab +bc +ac))\times(a+b+c)$
Based on that if $a +b +c=0$, $a^3 +b^3 +c^3=3abc$.
Then $abc=\frac{a^3 +b^3 +c^3}{3}$ ,so $abc\times\frac{a^2 + b^2 +c^2}{2}=\frac{a^3 + b^3 +c^3}{3}\times\frac{a^2 + b^2 +c^2}{2}$
Lastly I need to prove that $\frac{a^5 +b^5 +c^5}{5}$ is equal two previous formulas.
Solution in the book goes like this $(a^3 + b^3 +c^3)\times(a^2 +b^2 + c^2)=a^5 + b^5 + c^5 + a^2b^2(a+b) +b^2c^2(b+c) +c^2a^2(c+a)=a^5 +b^5 +c^5 -a^2b^2c - ab^2c^2 -a^2bc^2=a^5 +b^5 +c^5 -abc(ab +bc +ca)$
So far I understood however I can't understand this transformation, how did we went from here to there:
$a^5 +b^5 +c^5 -abc(ab +bc +ca)=a^5 +b^5 +c^5 +\frac{1}{2}\times abc(a^2 +b^2 +c^2)$

What additional assumptions are being made? The intermediate equality otherwise does not seem to hold.

Only thing that I can add which I think is visible from the beggining is that $(a^3 +b^3 +c^3)(a^2 +b^2 +c^2)=3abc(a^2 +b^2 +c^2)$

I don't get it. According to your calculation, where is $(abc)^2$?

Doesn't hold for $a=b=1,c=-2$, for example. Are you sure there's no other condition?

I made edit ,my mistake,it's not $\frac{a^3 +b^3 +c^3}{3} *abc$ but $\frac{a^2 +b^2 +c^2}{2} *abc$

No other condition,when I used chatgpt it found it was true by brutal force

Edit your tittle from which one has  $\dfrac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3}=1$

Good eye,I missed that

FYI Now that you've seen how to do this, try this variant   and this variant

In which way is this a [tag:linear-algebra] question?

All these operations have been done in accordance to the fact that $a+b+c=0$.
$$a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ca)=-2(ab+bc+ca)..(i)$$
$$a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc...(ii)$$
Then
$$(i)×(ii)=(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a^3+b^3+c^3)=-6abc(ab+bc+ca)$$
$$\implies a^5+b^5+c^5 -abc(ab+bc+ca)=-6abc(ab+bc+ca)$$
$$\implies \frac{a^5+b^5+c^5}{5}=-abc(ab+bc+ca)= abc \frac{-2(ab+bc+ca)}{2}=abc\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}$$

emphasis on Vieta formulas  and recurrence relation....  Let $\sigma_2 = bc + ca + ab$ and $\sigma_3 = abc. $  We are told $\sigma_1 = a+b+c = 0$  Then $a,b,c$ are the three roots of $$   x^3 + \sigma_2 x - \sigma_3$$
We get relations $   a^3 + \sigma_2 a - \sigma_3$  or
$a^3 = -\sigma_2  a + \sigma_3$   and then $b^3 = -\sigma_2  b + \sigma_3,$ $c^3 = -\sigma_2  c + \sigma_3.$
Next, let $S_1 = a+b+c = 0, $ $S_2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2,$  generally $S_n = a^n + b^n + c^n$
We know $S_1 = 0$  and $S_2 = -2 \sigma_2$ For any $n \geq 3$  we have $a^n = - \sigma_2 a^{n-2} + \sigma_3 a^{n-3},$  same for $b,c$  add, we get recurrence
$$  S_n = -\sigma_2 S_{n-2} + \sigma_3 S_{n-3}  $$
Here are my results; please let me know of errors.
$$  S_1 = 0 $$
$$ S_2 = -2 \sigma_2$$
$$ S_3 = 3 \sigma_3 $$
$$ S_4 = 2 \sigma_2^2 $$
$$ S_5 = -5 \sigma_2 \sigma_3$$
$$ S_6 = -2 \sigma_2^3 + 3 \sigma_3^2 $$
$$ S_7 = 7 \sigma_2^2 \sigma_3 $$
$$S_8 = 2 \sigma_2^4 - 8 \sigma_2 \sigma_3^2  $$
$$  S_9 = -9 \sigma_2^3 \sigma_3 + 3 \sigma_3^3   $$
$$   S_{10} =      -2\sigma_2^5 + 15 \sigma_2^2 \sigma_3^2  $$
$$  S_{11} = 11\sigma_2^4 \sigma_3 - 11 \sigma_2 \sigma_3^3   $$
$$ S_{12}  =  2   \sigma_2^6 - 24   \sigma_3^2   \sigma_2^3 + 3   \sigma_3^4 $$
$$ S_{13}  =  -13   \sigma_3   \sigma_2^5 + 26   \sigma_3^3   \sigma_2^2 $$
$$  S_{14} = -2   \sigma_2^7 + 35   \sigma_3^2   \sigma_2^4 - 14   \sigma_3^4   \sigma_2  $$
I like the 11... You can see that $\frac{S_2 S_3}{S_5}  $ is a constant (not involving $a,b,c$), also
$\frac{S_3 S_4}{S_7}  $  is a constant

Small typo for $n \geq 3$: $a^n=-\sigma_2 a^{n-2} + \sigma_3 a^{n-3}$. Otherwise, looks good!

There are exactly two identities in this form: if $a + b + c = 0$, then
$$\frac{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}{2}\cdot \frac{a^3 + b^3 + c^3}{3} = \frac{a^5 + b^5 + c^5}{5},$$
and
$$\frac{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}{2}\cdot \frac{a^5 + b^5 + c^5}{5} = \frac{a^7 + b^7 + c^7}{7}.$$
Many years ago, I saw the second one. At that time, I consider the following problem:
Problem. Find all positive integers $1 < m \le n$ such that there exists constant $C$
such that if $x + y + z = 0$, then $(x^m + y^m + z^m)(x^n + y^n + z^n) = C(x^{m+n} + y^{m + n} + z^{m+n})$.
All the four solutions are
$$\frac{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}{2}\cdot \frac{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}{2} = 2\cdot \frac{x^4 + y^4 + z^4}{4}, \tag{1}$$
and
$$\frac{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}{2}\cdot \frac{x^3 + y^3 + z^3}{3} = \frac{x^5 + y^5 + z^5}{5},\tag{2}$$
and
$$\frac{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}{2}\cdot \frac{x^5 + y^5 + z^5}{5} = \frac{x^7 + y^7 + z^7}{7}, \tag{3}$$
and
$$\frac{x^3 + y^3 + z^3}{3}\cdot \frac{x^4 + y^4 + z^4}{4} = \frac12 \cdot \frac{x^7 + y^7 + z^7}{7}. \tag{4}$$
Proof.
Case 1. $m, n$ are both even
Letting
$x = 1, y = -1, z = 0$, we have $C = 2$.
Letting $x = 1, y = 1, z= -2$,
we have $(2 + 2^m)(2 + 2^n) = 2(2 + 2^{m+n})$
or $(2^m - 2)(2^n - 2) = 4$
which results in $m = n = 2$. This is (1).
Case 2. $m, n$ are both odd
Letting $x = 1, y = -1, z = 0$, we have $C = 0$. Letting $x = 1, y = 1, z = -2$,
we get a contradiction. So this case is impossible.
Case 3. $m$ is even, $n$ is odd
Letting $z = 1, y = -1 - x$, we have
$$\left(2x^m + \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \binom{m}{k}x^k + 2\right)\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}x^k
= C\sum_{k=1}^{m+n-1}\binom{m+n}{k}x^k. \tag{A1}$$
Comparing respectively the coefficients of $x^{m + n - 1}$ and $x^{m+n-3}$ in both sides of (A1), we have
$$2n = (m + n)C, \tag{A2}$$
and
\begin{align*}
 &2\binom{n}{n-3}1_{n\ge 4} + \binom{m}{m-1}\binom{n}{n-2} + \binom{m}{m-2}\binom{n}{n-1}1_{m\ge 3}\\[6pt]
 &\qquad + 2\binom{n}{n+m-3}1_{m= 2}\\[6pt]
  ={}& C\binom{m+n}{m+n-3}. \tag{A3}
\end{align*}
All solution of the system of equations (A2) and (A3) are $(m, n) = (2, 3), (2, 5)$ (easy).
These are (2) and (3).
Case 4. $m$ is odd, $n$ is even
Letting $x = 1, y = -1 - x$, we have
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}x^k\right)\left(2x^n + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}x^k + 2\right) = C\sum_{k=1}^{m+n-1}\binom{m+n}{k}x^k. \tag{A4}$$
Comparing respectively the coefficients of $x^{m + n - 1}$ and $x^{m+n-3}$ in both sides of (A4), we have
$$2m = (m + n)C, \tag{A5}$$
and
\begin{align*}
 2\binom{m}{m-3}1_{m\ge 4} + \binom{m}{m-2}\binom{n}{n-1} + \binom{m}{m-1}\binom{n}{n-2} = C\binom{m+n}{m+n-3}. \tag{A6}
\end{align*}
$(m, n)= (3, 4)$ is the only solution of the system of equations (A5) and (A6). This is (4).
We are done.
